# How to Encode URL in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular7

i tried to encode a mobile number starting with country code "+91" to %2B..using code

```
{ 
 this.uri = "+919658452565;
 this.res = encodeURIComponent(this.uri)
}
```

at end of encoding am getting %2B919658452565;

but when i pass this.uri in URL params

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('personContactPhNo', this.uri);                                                                  this.baseURL= "https://sfghfhfhfghtgj.com/"; 
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params }) 
this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL+'Dev', options)
```

am getting error as %252B919658452565...
help here to solve this issue

Comment: Its being double encoded, %25 is the code for %. So something is already doing an encode are you sure you need to do it yourself

Comment: Not related to your problem, but do seriously consider migrating your project from using `@angular/http` to using HttpClient package in `@angular/common/http`. Http package has been totally removed from Angular 8 (released in May 2019). See [link](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations). `URLSearchParams` and `RequestOptions` are part of Http package, their API is no longer hosted in Angular official docs. You might as well migrate now than try to fix a problem in an already-removed package only to have to fix it again when you migrate in the future.

Comment: As Patrick Evans said, try leaving out your line when you use `encodeURIComponent()`. Clearly your URLs are being encoded anyway by Angular.